# Creating AWS EC2 instance image using saltstack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, salt-stack, devops, salt-cloud

Has anybody tried creating AWS AMI(image) using saltstack.

I tried using it was able to create new instance from existing AMIs but how to create image using salt-cloud?

Also attempted by using boto_ec2 but its give error that Module 'boto_ec2' is not available.

Comment: Did you check this http://docs.logilab.org/salt-ami-cloud-builder/how-to-build-an-ami.html

Comment: yes but i what to create AMI from existing AWS instance.

Comment: did you have the boto python module installed that is required for the boto_ec2 execution module?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in 2 steps:

1. you need to take a snapshot of your volume
2. you can create an AMI from a given snapshots

You can see all saltstack ec2 commands at https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/clouds/all/salt.cloud.clouds.ec2.html

1. create the snapshots : **create_snapshot**

   ```
   salt-cloud -f create_snapshot my-ec2-config volume_id=vol-351d8826
   salt-cloud -f create_snapshot my-ec2-config volume_id=vol-351d8826 \
   description="My Snapshot Description"
   ```
2. create the AMI : **register_image**

This command creates an ami from a snapshot

```
salt-cloud -f register_image my-ec2-config ami_name=my_ami \
description="my description" root_device_name=/dev/xvda snapshot_id=snap-xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: But i wanted to create another clone given a instance ids or a list of ids. as this has to be done for say 50 servers. as this process is not help in automation.

Comment: What you should do then is use the [CloudClient](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/clients/#salt.cloud.CloudClient) and write a python script to automate running this over all the servers that you want images of.